# Filtering certain parts of a string list into another list

Tags: python

In an assignment we were handed the script of a play and the task is to extraxt the monologue of a certain character. I loaded the txt document to my python script and converted it into a list in which each line is a list element. The script is similar to the following text:

CHARACTER A

Hello Madame! My name is character A.
How are you?

CHARACTER B

Hello Character A! My name is character B.
I am fine, I hope you are, too.

CHARACTER A

Yes, I am fine too.

Now we are trying to get only the text of character A into another list and convert it back into a txt file. As you can imagine the script is a lot longer and there are a lot more characters included. We made a list containing all the character names except for the one whose text is needed.
How can we write a code, which basically goes through all the lines starts saving the lines everytime when it says 'CHARACTER A' and stops as soon as another character, listed in the character list, starts talking.

This is what has been tried so far:

```
Character_A_monologue = []
i = 0

for line in Text:
    if "CHARACTER A" in line:
        Character_A_monologue.append(Text[i])
        if Text[i+1] != Characters:
            Character_A_monologue.append(MB_Text_new[i+1])
            if Text[i+2] != Characters:
                Character_A_monologue.append(MB_Text_new[i+2])
    i += 1
```

We have been trying to detect when Character A starts talking and then check all the lines which follow, but is not really working and there is not automatic stop for when the loop detects a name out of the list Characters.

Comment: Could you include what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Using re, since there's no newline char in lines,

pattern "CHARACTER A\n\n(.*)" seems to get you CHARACTER A's lines.

```
import re

text = "CHARACTER A\n\nHello Madame! My name is character A. How are you?\n\nCHARACTER B\n\nHello Character A! My name is character B. I am fine, I hope you are, too.\n\nCHARACTER A\n\nYes, I am fine too."

print(re.findall("CHARACTER A\n\n(.*)", text))
```

result:

['Hello Madame! My name is character A. How are you?', 'Yes, I am fine too.']